# Javascript delete button

Tags: javascript, button

I'm having trouble making my delete button work on the js side from html. I'm new to learning web development! I seriously need some help/ guidance. Much appreciated.

This is my html:

`enter code here`

Notebook Delete!

Spinach Delete!

Rice Delete!

Birthday Cakes Delete!

Candles Delete!

This is my javascript:

```
     var button = document.getElementById("enter"); //getelement is to obtain infor from button
     var input = document.getElementById("userinput"); //getelement to obtain infor from input
     var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
     var li = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
     var delt = document.getElementsByClassName("delt");

   function delt(event) {
       if (button.onclick === "Delete") {
       event.target.parentNode.remove();
     }
  }

   ul.addEventListener("click", delt);
```

Comment: Java is not JavaScript. Never confuse them

Comment: onclick isn't a string so you code will never execute the if block

Comment: Your conditional will never be true. It's not at all clear what `button.onclick` is supposed to be, but it isn't going to be a string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all u can't repeat names so u should change delt function's name

As a recomendation try to name functions according it's functionality

```js
function deleteItem(e){
  console.log("Button element", e)
  e.parentElement.remove()
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1 <button onclick="deleteItem(this)">Delete</button></li>
  <li>Item 2 <button onclick="deleteItem(this)">Delete</button></li>
  <li>Item 3 <button onclick="deleteItem(this)">Delete</button></li>
  <li>Item 4 <button onclick="deleteItem(this)">Delete</button></li>
  <li>Item 5 <button onclick="deleteItem(this)">Delete</button></li>
</ul>
```

By writing `deleteItem(this)` you pass element object to function

If you want your button to pass `event` to function then just change `this` for `event`

Btw, it's not a good practice to have your HTML && JS code in the same place, so you should do it this way

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){
  // Once DOM is loaded add onclick function
  // Select all buttons with class "btn-delete"
  document.querySelectorAll('button.btn-delete').forEach(el => {
    // Walk each selected button and set onclick function
    // remember to declare event function within a wrapper if you're gonna pass a var
    el.onclick = () => deleteItem(el)
    /* "() => Code" is called arrow function
    * it's the same as a regular anonymous function
      function(){Code}
    */
    // if you want to just execute the function
    // el.onclick = deleteItem
  })
});
// Declare your function outer the DOMContentLoaded event listener
function deleteItem(e){
  // e is the element object, so you do not need to get .target
  e.parentElement.remove()
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1 <button class="btn-delete">Delete</button></li>
  <li>Item 2 <button class="btn-delete">Delete</button></li>
  <li>Item 3 <button class="btn-delete">Delete</button></li>
  <li>Item 4 <button class="btn-delete">Delete</button></li>
  <li>Item 5 <button class="btn-delete">Delete</button></li>
</ul>
```

They both works the same, but it'd be better for you to get used to that organization so when your code grows up it would not be spaghetti code

If you want to know more about that check this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Comment: Hey thanks so much for the help i really appreciate you taking the time to help out.. Do you have any recommendations of a great site/free source in practicing DOM.

Comment: @kre Glad the answer has been useful to u, if it solved your question please mark it as answer so the post can be closed, also to start development i'd recommend to use an ide and test your code locally by opening the .html file in a web browser, but if you still want it to be a online site i'd recommend [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)